# Import audio file from local or use a link from google drive?

Tags: performance, audio, google-drive-api, bootstrap-4, mp3

I want to know which of the options has the best performance: import a local mp3 file (src="local/audio.mp3") or use it from a url provided by google drive (src="https://googledrive.com/audio.mp3). 
Im using an accordion nested in bootstrap, and which one of the items contains an audio file. For better performance, I want the audio file to load only when the accordion is opened.

Comment: Obviously the local file is better since it's already "there" and has no need for internet (waiting to download). But it will only work on that specific computer so do this if your machine is doing a public display/kiosk type of task.

Comment: With "local" i mean that is on the root of the website. Because when is on the root of the page, your browser needs to download the file (or at least a compress version) and keep it on cache, right? In that case i think a url will be better but not sure

Comment: Browser needs to download the file regardless of where it's saved. If it's 100 mb then 100 mb will be downloaded from either yours or some external server. If the accordion has code to begin a download when opened then each "open" will restart a download. To avoid that, better to have the download code elsewhere (do once on page load, an audio tag with no controls) and the accordion "open" part has code to play the file (access by `<audio>` tag's ID)

Comment: _"have the download code elsewhere"_ means outside of the accordion code. The accordion part just triggers when to play/stop (or pause, if you need to continue playback from last point).

Comment: Hmmmm understood. But that wont make my website slow? Because i have like 500 audio files. Check my website www.bibliotecafalada.com and go to "Producoes". You will see